# how to get two table joined data exclude some conditional data of one table in mysql?

Tags: mysql, sql

I have two tables: Student and fee

**student**

| sid | name | roll_no |
| --- | --- | --- |
| 1 | John | 22 |
| 2 | Karina | 32 |
| 3 | Navin | 42 |

**fee**

| fid | s_id | month | fee |
| --- | --- | --- | --- |
| 1 | 2 | January | 1000 |
| 2 | 3 | January | 1200 |
| 3 | 2 | Fabruary | 1000 |

I want to get students (who not paid fee) for Fabruary : like this...

| Student id | Name | Roll No | January | February |
| --- | --- | --- | --- | --- |
| 1 | John | 22 | 0 | 0 |
| 3 | Navin | 42 | 1200 | 0 |

**My code is :**

```
SELECT s.sid,s.name,s.roll_no,f.fee
from student s 
 left join
     fee f 
     ON f.fid = s.sid 
AND f.month = 'January' 
where s.sid NOT IN  (SELECT s_id from fee
                     where month = 'February') 
order by c.id;
```

I got zero value in both months for all students
------Thanks in advance-------

**After correction** this code works in mysql workbench but not in java application.

```
SELECT 

s.sid,s.name,s.roll_no, ifnull(f.fee,0) as pre_month,0 as current_month

from student s 

 left join

 fee f 

 ON f.s_id = s.sid 

 AND f.month = 'January' 

 where s.sid NOT IN  

   (SELECT s_id from fee

   where month = 'February') 

 order by s.sid;
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

For the results you want, I would suggest conditional aggregation and a `having` clause:

```
SELECT s.sid, s.name, s.roll_no,
       SUM(CASE WHEN f.month = 'January' THEN f.fee ELSE 0 END) as january,
       SUM(CASE WHEN f.month = 'February' THEN f.fee ELSE 0 END) as february
FROM student s LEFT JOIN
     fee f 
     ON f.fid = s.sid AND f.month = 'January' 
GROUP BY s.sid, s.name, s.roll_no
HAVING SUM(CASE WHEN f.month = 'February' THEN f.fee ELSE 0 END) = 0 AND
       SUM(CASE WHEN f.month = 'January' THEN f.fee ELSE 0 END) > 0;
```

[Here](https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=mysql_8.0&fiddle=0521c235eb661353e39d2f80cc5c0c34) is a db<>fiddle.

Note that storing month names in a column is usually a really bad idea.  It does not distinguish between the years, for instance.  It is much better to use a date.

Comment: Your query contradicts your wording, "`having` clause"

Comment: Thank you @GordonLinoff. It gets empty rows.

Comment: @LPanthiManiv . . . I fixed the filtering logic and added a db<>fiddle.  Note:  Your question says "not paid in February".  However, the results suggest that you really mean "paid in January but not in February".

Comment: @Gordon Linoff   Thank you.  Yes may be or may not be paid in January but not in February.

Comment: @LPanthiManiv . . . You can remove the January condition from the `HAVING` clause.

Comment: @GordonLinoff Karina has paid in February so Karina would not be shown in the table.

Answer (score 0):

You can use a left join to join the students with their fees, and then a having clause to filter the list down to those who don't have one for February.  The below query should get you a list of all students who did not pay a fee for February.

It also looked like you might be using the wrong column on the fee table for the join.  It looked like you might want `s_id` instead of `fid`.

```
select s.*
from students s
left join fee f on f.s_id=s.sid and f.month='February'
having f.fid is null;
```